# easy button for adding column

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

I right click on my table in ssms 2008 and select Script Table as / Drop and Create Table to new window and I try to run the script but get an error:

```
Could not drop table because it is referenced by a foreign key constraint
```

What was the point of the Drop and Create generate script then?

Thanks,

rod.

Comment: A new column will not have constraints defined. What constraints are you talking about? What button are you talking about?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Management Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the Drop and Create generate script is exactly what you'd think - it gives you an easy way to script out dropping and re-creating a table.  However you can't drop a table if other tables reference it via foreign key constraints, which is why you're getting the error message.

If you're just trying to add a column, you can right-click the table in Enterprise Manager and click Modify and just add the column in design view.  There's no need to drop the table just to add a column.  (And it's especially an awful approach if the table has data in it.)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to add a column to an existing table? Write the ALTER TABLE statement yourself instead of relying on SQL Server Management Studio to do it for you:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
ADD ColumnName int
```